# How is a flat-shaded cube's mesh data organized?

Tags: opengl, mesh

For a flat-shaded cube, there are eight vertices and each vertex has 3 normal vectors, while for a smooth-shaded cube there is only one normal vector for each vertex. I wonder to know how is the mesh data organized for a flat-shaded cube. Is every vertex considered three times and each time the vertex normal is different and corresponding to three connected faces' normal? If so, the mesh data passed to buffer for draw calls like glDrawElements is the same size as that for regular draw call (for example, glDrawArrays), as for both of them, each vertex appears three times in the attribute buffer.

For smooth-shaded cube it is easy to image how the mesh data is organized, that each data only appears one time in the vertices array, and there is only one normal vector for each of them.